# Что происходит со сборкой?

Tags: c#, рефлексия

Получилась следующая ситуация...

1) Создаем в приложении домен.
2) Загружаем в него через `DoCallBack` сборку `Assembly.Load(...)`
3) Из главного домена достаем сборки ранее созданного и например, показываем их имена.
4) Смотрим какие сборки есть в главном домене, а конкретней - там появилась эта сборка которую мы загрузили в другой домен.

То есть, загружая сборку в другой домен, если обратиться с методу `GetAssemblies`, загруженные сборки появляются и в основном домене, при этом они не просто туда переносятся, они копируются - их можно использоваться в обоих доменах.

Если зациклить данный процесс и наблюдать за памятью, то видно что она растет, значит сборки загружаются по новой в память каждый раз.

Самый главный вопрос, почему? Как избавиться от переноса сборки в основной домен? Тут даже не в памяти дело, а в том что основной домен держит референс на сборку и не дает её удалить, например. А инфу как-то вытаскивать надо.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main ( string [ ] args )
        {
            var appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("TestDomain");
            appDomain.DoCallBack(LoadModule);

            var assembly = appDomain.GetAssemblies().Single( t => t.GetName().Name == "TestModule" );

            foreach ( var assembly1 in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() )
            {
                Console.WriteLine( assembly1.FullName );
            }
        }

        private static void LoadModule()
        {
            Assembly.Load( "TestModule" );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Покажите код. Моё предположение состоит в том, что в пункте 3 Вы передаёте `Assembly` объекты из дополнительного домена в основной, что естественно приводит к загрузке сборок в основной домен (и вовсе не обязательно тех, которые были загружены в дополнительный).

Comment: @PetSerAl, ничего я не передаю, хватит одного вызова `GetAssemblyes`, я же написал.

Comment: Хм. Вы вызываете `appDomain.GetAssemblies()`, и для каждого из них вызываете `GetName()`. Думаю, это грузит ваши сборки в _основной_ домен.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Существует две возможности передать объект через границу домена приложения:

1. Через прокси. Для объектов наследующих от `System.MarshalByRefObject`. При этом все вызовы методов на прокси объекте автоматически перенаправляются в домен приложения, которому принадлежит исходный объект.
2. Через бинарную сериализацию. Для объектов, которые её поддерживают. При этом создаётся копия объекта, которая более не связана с исходным объектом.

При этом класс `System.AppDomain` наследует от `System.MarshalByRefObject`, в то время как класс `System.Reflection.Assembly` нет. То есть вызов `appDomain.GetAssemblies()` в Вашем коде будет перенаправлен в дополнительный домен приложения, после чего результат его работы (`Assembly[]`) необходимо будет передать в основной домен приложения: сериализовать в дополнительном домене и десериализовать в основном домене. Данная передача `Assembly` объектов в основной домен приложения и приводит к загрузке в него сборок.

Чтобы избежать загрузки сборок в основной домен, не передавайте в него объекты, для десериализации которых необходимо загрузить сборку. Как то `System.Reflection.Assembly` объект, представляющий сборку, `System.Type` объект, представляющий любой тип из сборки, экземпляр любого типа из сборки.

Например имена сборок можно извлекать в дополнительном домене приложения, а в основной передавать только строки:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

class Program
    {
        static void Main ( string [ ] args )
        {
            var appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("TestDomain");
            appDomain.DoCallBack(LoadModule);

            var worker = (Worker)appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(Worker).Assembly.FullName, typeof(Worker).FullName);

            foreach ( var assemblyFullName1 in worker.GetAssembliesFullName() )
            {
                Console.WriteLine( assemblyFullName1 );
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            foreach ( var assembly1 in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() )
            {
                Console.WriteLine( assembly1.FullName );
            }
        }

        private static void LoadModule()
        {
            Assembly.Load( "TestModule" );
        }
    }

class Worker : MarshalByRefObject {
    public string[] GetAssembliesFullName() {
        return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Select(a => a.FullName).ToArray();
    }
}
```